# Should I use typescript in all the layers of the MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, mean-stack

I chose the MEAN stack to develop my web application mainly because I will be using javascript across all the layers.
One language to rule them all, right?
And then I heard about typescript, and I decided to use it.
The thing is typescript is mainly used with angular and not the other layers of the stack. So choosing typescript means losing the best thing about the MEAN stack.
I still want the benefits of typescript along with the:

> One language to rule them all!

In other words, I want to use BOTH typescript&MEAN stack, to develop my web-application, would you advise me to do this?

I just found-out about this "new" stack called tsmean https://www.tsmean.com.  It seems the perfect answer for my question! 
However, I am  scared since it is still a new technology and there’snt a large community behind it like the MeanJS stack  community. Also the lack of reliable tutorials makes me a bit hesitant to use it.

On the other hand, my web-application is relatively small and simple and in an article on medium (https://medium.com/@TypeMean/building-the-ts-mean-stack-first-impressions-c2bf1db2bef1), the creator of tsmean wrote that in such conditions, using tsmean can be a good decision.
In a nutshell, I will be creating a web-app version of the functionalities provided by a simple excell sheet. So I believe tsmean is the right choice for me!

Comment: `tsmean` is just a starter that puts together some cool technologies. You can easily implement it yourself, while adding only the tools your project needs and you care about. If your project is going to be small as you're saying, you probably won't need all the things that `tsmean` and other starters provide.

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO because it's opinion-based (and "should" even more so). I don't see how it got an uovote.

Comment: @DaveNewton please explain to me how come this question is off-topic? Are opinion-based questions invalid?

Comment: @MassimilianoSartoretto Thank you!

Comment: @AhmedGhrib Yes; https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Even if it wasn't, it's still kind of lame--TS is just transpiled JS; you can use it at whatever layer you want.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from using TS with Express or Node that would suddenly "violate" what MEAN is. "One language to rule them all" is certainly one approach, but "right tool for the job" might serve you better.

Comment: TypeScript is JavaScript with strong typing abilities. Anything that can be written in JavaScript can also be written in TypeScript. TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript so really, when you deploy your TypeScript code, it becomes a JavaScript application. I enjoy TypeScript and have been using it for a few years now. Any package available to JavaScript is available to TypeScript. Both TypeScript and JavaScript are EcmaScript languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you want to use TypeScript throughout your MEAN stack, you can. TypeScript is literally JavaScript with strong typing abilities. This makes classes and method signatures much stronger than JavaScript by itself. Ultimately, TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript so any packages available to JavaScript are also available to TypeScript. Both are EcmaScript languages.